# returning 3 for tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: and Apple

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

I've discovered this currently hidden/private/undocumented option for an easy way to allow multiple selection in UITableView's in my app.

It works beautifully for me at the moment, and yes, I'm aware of the risk that stuff can change in future iOS updates..

My question can anyone confirm **from their experience** that Apple will actually reject / accept applications using it? Can they even discover that you're using it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can scan for you using I and could reject it. I suggest you raise a feature request to...

http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: I have seen many things that will always slip past Apple, so what i was looking for is hearing actual experience with this specific one.

Comment: That is not worth asking. Apple are renowned for approving one app and declining another. Simply down to luck which in my eyes for a commercial app should not be chanced.

Comment: true that in regards to some features apple may or may not approve, but that's a potential answer, it's not always the case. There are many cases where it's "safe" to assume a feature that apple claims will get your app rejected will get on the app store, so what i'm asking is whether this is the case.